# Error en XAMPP Apache shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: apache, xampp

Intento ejecutar **Apache**, pero me manda el siguiente mensaje de error, ya lo desinstalé y lo volví a instalar pero sigue apareciendo este error, alguna ayuda?

```
06:03:00 p.m.  [Apache]     Status change detected: stopped 
06:03:00 p.m.  [Apache]     Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. 
06:03:00 p.m.  [Apache]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,  
06:03:00 p.m.  [Apache]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. 
06:03:00 p.m.  [Apache]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check 
06:03:00 p.m.  [Apache]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues 
06:03:00 p.m.  [Apache]     If you need more help, copy and post this 
06:03:00 p.m.  [Apache]     entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: tienes algun otro programa que pudiera estar usando el mismo puerto que xampp como skype?

Comment: No, de hecho acabo de formatear mi computadora, anteriormente me funcionaba sin problemas, hasta ahorita no he descargado otros programas que puedan estar ocupando el puerto

Comment: Debes indicar parte del contenido del archivo log en donde ocurre el error para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Normalmente son errores de configuración del fichero httpf.conf del servidor apache. ¿No as añadido nada manualmente en dicho fichero?

Comment: De dónde lo descargaste? Probá cambiando el puerto de apache por 8080.